# Updater Crash - All pages blank

Tags: devdemon-updater

I just attempted to use Updater 3.2.4 to update my test site from EE2.7.2 to 2.10.1. The process froze up while it was installing EE. Now all my pages, both CP and front end are just blank pages with empty html, head and body tags. I don't know if this is a database issue or a file issue. Has anyone seen this before? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Open your main index.php file and set error reporting all the way on! Then report back with your errors.

Comment: Thanks jrothafer. I just decided to go through with a manual update and that seems to have cleared everything up. Not sure why Updater crapped out.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go ahead and do a manual update and that seems to have cleared everything up. Also updated all add-ons. Not sure why Updater crapped out though.